# Floating point in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point

I'm currently trying to get an average as a floating point number, rounded to the nearest .001

Being pretty new to floating point instructions and such, this is what I have so far from the reading and searching that I've done.

**sum**: a DWORD holding the value 90 (sum of **acc** number of items)

**acc**: a DWORD holding the value 7 (number of items)

**res**: a DWORD to hold the answer.

In the end, edx has the value 0. Why is this?
Additionally, how do I round floating point?

Or...is there a better way to do this?

My asm:

```
   push dword ptr sum
   fild dword ptr [esp]
   push dword ptr acc
   fild dword ptr [esp]
   add esp,4
   fdiv st(0), st(1)
   sub esp,4
   fstp dword ptr [esp]
   pop eax
   add esp,4
   mov edx, eax
```

Also, I tried this:

```
   finit
   fild sum
   fidiv acc
   frndint
   fist res
   mov eax, res
```

But...this results in: 2147483648 (DWORD range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have a lot of unneeded stack operations in your code, however, there is a more sinister problem here, storing the fp result in a `DWORD` will truncate it, so there is no point in round it unless you plan on round to the nearest integer value (which is what your second attempt does).

As such I'll base an example off your second attempt:

```
PUSH ECX
FILD [ESP]
PUSH EDX
FILD [ESP]
FDIV
FRNDINT
ADD ESP,4
FISTP DWORD PTR [ESP]
POP EAX
RETN
```

this function assumes the value in `ECX`, the count in `EDX` and returns a rounded average in `EAX`. for here you can just change it to use your globals, or call it as a function using your globals

Comment: I replaced the ecx/edx with sum/acc and at the end eax still returns the DWORD range of 2147483648. :/

Comment: @Dacto: then there is something wrong on your end, as this works find for me (returning the expected 13, using your inputs). Try running through it in a debugger

Comment: Thank you. Debugger worked it out. Foolish problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: Rounding to 0.001 isn't a very good idea, because this is an infinite periodic fraction in binary.

Comment: I know...but I need to stop some where ;) but also trying to learn how to round to a specific place in general with floating point.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but at least the 2nd bit of code seems valid. Whether it does what you want is another question. It does this:

```
   finit
   fild sum        ;//ST(0) = 90
   fidiv acc       ;//ST(0) = ST(0) / acc = 90 / 7 = 12.857..
   frndint         ;//ST(0) = 13
   fist res        ;//RES= ST(0) = 13
   mov eax, res    ;//EAX = RES = 13
```

In other words, you are calculating round(90/7) = 13.

Now, this is a straightforward division, not an average. You'd obviously calculate an average by summing over N items and then dividing by the number of items.

The second thing is that you are working with integers, not with floating point values: the `fIld`, `fIdiv` and `fIst` instructions work are designed to work with integer, not floating point values. If you store a value from the FPU into memory with `fIst` rather than `fst/fstp` this value in memory will be an integer value, not a floating point value. Is it this you want?

To store a floating point value from the FPU to memory pointed to by `[eax]`, you can use

```
   fstp dword ptr [eax] ;// Store Single-Precision Floating point value (4 bytes)
   fstp qword ptr [eax] ;// Store Double-Precision Floating point value (8 bytes)
   fstp tbyte ptr [eax] ;// Store Long Double-Precision Floating point value (10 bytes)
```

The Single and Double stores (but not the `tbyte ptr`) also work with `fst` instead of `fstp`.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want it to do (preferably I'd like to round to the nearest .001 - understanding that I would be using fst/fstp for that). However, regardless, res/eax still result in 2147483648

Comment: @Dacto -  I cannot confirm your result. When I ran the code, I had the value of 13 in EAX

Comment: I figured it out and get 13 also now :]. How would I go about rounding to the nearest .001? I changed the fIxx to fld, fdiv, and fstp, but now I get the value of 1108502118 in eax

Comment: @Dacto - there's no single instruction that just rounds to an arbitrary precision for you; you have to write the code for that yourself. If you have trouble, I think it would be easiest if you ask this in a separate question.